# nth partial sum of the series for $\zeta(2)$

Tags: calculus

Please, can you advice me, how to determine the $n$th partial sum of the finite series $1 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + \dots + 1/n^2$?
Thank you very much.

Comment: There isn't a nice closed form. You can cook up integral representations, however.

Comment: The standard notation is $$ H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Comment: This was discussed by several users at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685435/).

Comment: [This OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C49%2C820%2C21076&language=english&go=Search) asserts that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{(n!)^2}\left({n+1\brack 2}^2-2{n+1\brack1}{n+1\brack3}\right)$, where $a\brack b$ is a [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). That's sort of a closed formula if you have a way to compute $a\brack b$ easily.

Comment: My previous comment is just smoke and mirrors though, since ${n+1\brack 2}$ is not any easier to compute than $H_n^{(2)}$.

Comment: The proof of the cited identity by @alex.jordan can be found at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893565).