# Relation between Stirling numbers of first kind and harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, stirling-numbers

We have the following nice relations for Striling numbers of the first kind
$${n\brack 2} = \Gamma(n) H_{n-1}$$
$${n\brack 3} = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{2} \big((H_{n-1})^2-H_{n-1}^{(2)}\big)$$

Where

$$H^{(p)}_n = \sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k^p}, \,\,\,H^{(1)}_n \equiv H_n$$

**Questions**

- I want an algebraic proof (not combinatorial) for the previous relations.
- Is there a "simple" general formula in terms of the harmonic numbers for

$${n\brack k} = {?}$$

Comment: What does $H_{n-1}^{(2)}$ mean? Shouldn't it be $H_{n-1}^2$?

Comment: @YuriyS, see my edits.

Comment: @YuriyS: $H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$. We are talking about the Taylor coefficients of $\log(1-x)^m$, so we may find the expression of ${n\brack s+1}$ by considering the expression of ${n\brack s}$, removing the $\Gamma$ part, dividing by $n$ and summing over $n=1,2,\ldots,N$ through summation by parts.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai, I see, thanks

Comment: These are discussed and proved at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893565/).

Answer (score 1):

An idea to get a general formula is given in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k) Wikipedia article: we write $$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n+1\brack k+1}x^k=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac xk\right)=\exp\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac xk\right)\\=\exp\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}\left(\frac xk\right)^j=\exp\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}H_n^{(j)}x^j$$ and apply [exponentiation of a power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula). The result can be written as $${n+1\brack k+1}=n!(-1)^k\sum_{\substack{a_1,\,a_2,\,\ldots,\,a_k\,\geqslant\,0\\a_1+2a_2+\ldots+ka_k=k}}\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{a_j!}\left(-\frac{H_n^{(j)}}{j}\right)^{a_j}.$$