# A question on the Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, stirling-numbers

Let $c(n,k)$ be the $k^{th}$ unsigned Stirling number of the first kind. There are formulas for big $k$'s, namely,  $c(n,n-1)= \binom{n}{2}$ and $c(n,n-2) = \frac{3n-1}{4} \binom{n}{3}$.

I wonder whethere there are formulas for small $k$'s, e.g. $c(n,1), c(n,2)$?

Comment: Does your convention imply that $c\left(n,k\right)$ counts the number of permutations of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ having exactly $k$ cycles? In that case, $c\left(n,1\right)$ is simply the number of $n$-cycles, which is $\left(n-1\right)!$. As for $c\left(n,2\right)$, there is the formula $c\left(n,2\right) = \left(n-1\right)! H_{n-1}$, where $H_j$ denotes the $j$-th harmonic number $1/1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/j$. Barring a good formula for $H_j$, I don't think a good one exists for $c\left(n,2\right)$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thus, I wonder some closed form for $c(n,3)$ and the rest.

Comment: OEIS for $c(n,2)$: https://oeis.org/A000254. You can also find $c(n,3)$ there, though if $c(n,2)$ is hard to get a nice formula for, I can't imagine $c(n,3)$ would be much easier.

Comment: See the end of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k).

Comment: @metamorphy, thank you for your valuable comment. I checked the related part of the generalization. However, there is  'Pochhammer symbol', $(m)_{k}$ in the formula but it is not clear how it is used. The page of the symbol says that it may be used for either the rising or the falling factorial. Lastly, Wiki says that Pochhammer himself used it as $\binom{m}{k}$. Do you have any idea on this symbol and how it is used here?

Comment: Well, it has to be defined wherever it is used ;) Throughout that article, it means the *falling* factorial (as stated at the very beginning; one can confirm it by trying a few small $k$).

Comment: Just answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2096125) older question (asking basically the same).