# Convergence of a Series involving $\cos$ and $\log$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Does the following series converge?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos(2k(x-y))\log\big(\sin|\frac{x-y}{2}|\big)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: How $\log\sin\frac{x-y}{2}$ is defined when $\sin\frac{x-y}{2}<0$?

Comment: In my notes I had absolute value,typos in my LaTeX, edited it.

Comment: And... what do you think?

Comment: My impression is that it diverges.(since I feel certain operator is not nuclear)

Comment: Yes, the series behaves like the harmonic series, just see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today it is a fashion argument: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916085/prove-that-int-0-pi-2-ln2-cos-x-dx-frac-pi2-ln2-2-frac-pi324) and [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867461/a-closed-form-for-int-0-pi-2-x3-ln32-cos-x-mathrmdx), too.

We have that $\log(2\sin u)$ has a nice Fourier series:
$$\log(2\sin u)=-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2nu)}{n}\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I_k &=& \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(2k(x-y))\log\sin\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|\,dx\,dy\\ &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{x}\cos(2k(x-y))\log\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\,dy\,dx\\&=&2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}x\cos(2k(x-xt))\log\sin\frac{x-xt}{2}\,dt\,dx\\&=&2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}x\cos(2kxz)\log\left(2\sin\frac{xz}{2}\right)\,dz\,dx\\&=&-2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}x\cos(2kxz)\cos(nxz)\,dz\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now the last double integral equals $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ if $n=2k$,
$$4\frac{n^2+4k^2}{(n^2-4k^2)^2}$$
if $n$ is odd, zero otherwise, hence the contribute given by $n=2k$ makes the original double integral not summable over $k$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(2kx)\log\sin\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|\,dx\,dy< -\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{k}<-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\log K.$$