# Is there any closed form for $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^nx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\,d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

In my [post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-we-evaluate-the-integral-displaystyle-int_-0-1-frac-ln-x-sqrt-1-x-2-d-x-tag/answer/Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=268246022&share=be8b3a45&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer), I found that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2 .$$

Then I try to generalize the result to the integral by the same technique. $$
J_{n}:=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^nx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x
$$

Letting $x=\cos \theta $ converting $I_n$ into
\begin{aligned}
J_{n} &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} } \frac{\ln^n (\cos \theta)}{\sin \theta} \sin \theta d \theta \\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^{n}(\cos \theta) d \theta \end{aligned}

By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4392755/732917),
$$\begin{aligned}
(-2)^{n}J_n&= 2 \ln 2(-2)^{n-1} J_{n-1} + (n-1) !\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{2^{n-k}-2}{k_ !} \zeta(n-k) (-2)^{k} J_k \\J_n&= -\ln 2 J_{n-1} + (n-1) !\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k !} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-k-1}} \right)\zeta(n-k)  J_k
\end{aligned}
$$

which is a reduction formula for $J_n.$

For example, $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^2x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} d x&=-\ln 2 J_{1}+\frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) J_{0} \\
&=-\ln 2\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2\right)+\frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) J_{0} \\
&=\frac{\pi \ln ^{2} 2}{2}+\frac{\pi^{3}}{24},
\end{aligned}
$$

which is checked by [Wolframalpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB_0%5E1%20ln%5E2x%2F%28%E2%88%9A%281-x%5E2%29%29dx)

***My Question***

Is there any closed form for the integral?  Your comments and methods are warmly welcome.

Comment: If nothing else, $J_n$ for $n \geq 3$ will involve numbers like $\zeta(3)$ which can't be simplified further.  That may or may not count as a "closed form" in your book.

Comment: [Malmsten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Johan_Malmsten) determined related integrals which are essentially a derivative away from the simpler integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^n x}{1+x^2} \, dx$ and the answers are quite non-trivial, so I wouldn’t suspect your integral to have a closed-form.

Comment: Although, Mathematica does give $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^n x}{1+x^2} \, dx = (-1)^n 4^{-1-n} \Gamma (1+n) \left(\zeta\left(1+n,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(1+n,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$ for $\Re (n)>-1$, but I’m not sure about your integral.

Comment: You could try generalizing the [Fourier series approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492959/integrate-ln3-sinx-using-fourier-series) though evaluating the multisum in the general $n$-case will probably be very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Under the substitution $x^2 \to x$ we get that
$$I_{n,m} =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^n(x)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^m}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^n(x) x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)^{-m}\mathrm{d}x $$ Recalling the definition of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) we see that
\begin{align*}
B\left(\frac{1}{2}+t, 1-m\right) =& \int_0^{1} x^{-\frac{1}{2}+t}(1-x)^{-m}\mathrm{d}x \\
\mathbin{\color{blue}{\implies}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n}B\left(\frac{1}{2}+t, 1-m\right)\Bigg\vert_{t=0} =&\int_{0}^{1}\ln^n(x) x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)^{-m}\mathrm{d}x =2^{n+1}I_{n,m}
\end{align*}
So we get the generalization

> $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^n(x)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^m}\mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n}B\left(\frac{1}{2}+t, 1-m\right)\Bigg\vert_{t=0} \qquad \text{for }\ \  m<1,\ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

This result could technically be expanded in terms of polygamma functions using the [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), but I expect this will just result in a way messier expression.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer*

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^n(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\,dx$$ Using the binomial expansion of the denominator
$$I_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\, k!}\int_{0}^{1} x^{2k}\,\log^n(x)\,dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{2k}\,\log^n(x)\,dx=(-1)^n \frac{ \Gamma (n+1)}{(2 k+1)^{n+1} }$$
$$I_n=(-1)^n\frac{ n!}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 k+1)^{n+1}\,k!}$$ which I am unable to simplify even using special function. But, for a given $n$, this leads to the results.