# Another way of expressing $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\frac{H_{k+1}}{n-k+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In this post [Another way of expressing $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{H_{k+1}}{n-k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919572/another-way-of-expressing-sum-k-0n-frach-k1n-k1) I asked for a solution of the non-alternating series. How about the alternating series? Can we find a nice way of expressing this sum?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k\frac{H_{k+1}}{n-k+1}$$

Comment: Didn't you try to mimic my [previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919572/another-way-of-expressing-sum-k-0n-frach-k1n-k1) ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin I think it's a bit more complicated since it appears $\log(1-x) \log(1+x)$ in the numerator of the generating function.

Comment: I know because I was trying to imitate my previous answer. We got some sum with Digamma's, etc...